# Get multiple rows using FOR JSON clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Using PostgreSQL I can have multiple rows of json objects.

```
select (select ROW_TO_JSON(_) from (select c.name, c.age) as _) as jsonresult from employee as c
```

This gives me this result:

```
{"age":65,"name":"NAME"}
{"age":21,"name":"SURNAME"}
```

But in SqlServer when I use the FOR JSON AUTO clause it gives me an array of json objects instead of multiple rows.

```
select c.name, c.age from customer c FOR JSON AUTO

[{"age":65,"name":"NAME"},{"age":21,"name":"SURNAME"}]
```

How to get the same result format in SqlServer ?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 CTP3.2  added `without_array_wrapper`...  Sample: `select top 5 (select a.* for json path, without_array_wrapper) from sys.objects a`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By constructing separate JSON in each individual row:

```
SELECT (SELECT [age], [name] FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
FROM customer
```

There is an alternative form that doesn't require you to know the table structure (but likely has worse performance because it may generate a large intermediate JSON):

```
SELECT [value] FROM OPENJSON(
    (SELECT * FROM customer FOR JSON PATH)
)
```

Comment: @Mathew: yes, see updated question. I don't know of a way to do this that will have good performance; ask a separate question if that's a concern. (Or, you know, just write out the columns, `SELECT *` is recommended against for a reason.)

Comment: Still useful in 2022.

Comment: Worked like a charm, the only thing I was missing was the INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES option for null values that I wanted anyway, gonna leave it here, might help someone.

Answer (score 8):

no structure better performance

```
SELECT c.id, jdata.*
FROM customer c
  cross apply 
    (SELECT * FROM customer jc where jc.id = c.id FOR JSON PATH , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) jdata (jdata)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The other answers doesn`t work for me

Answer (score 0):

Same as Barak Yellin but more lazy:

1-Create this proc

```
CREATE PROC PRC_SELECT_JSON(@TBL VARCHAR(100), @COLS VARCHAR(1000)='D.*') AS BEGIN
EXEC('
SELECT X.O FROM ' + @TBL + ' D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ' + @COLS + '
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) X (O)
')
END
```

2-Can use either all columns or specific columns:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST ( X INT, Y VARCHAR(10), Z DATE )
INSERT #TEST VALUES (123, 'TEST1', GETDATE())
INSERT #TEST VALUES (124, 'TEST2', GETDATE())

EXEC PRC_SELECT_JSON #TEST

EXEC PRC_SELECT_JSON #TEST, 'X, Y'
```

If you're using PHP add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in the first row ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211150/exec-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-php)).