# MssqlRow to json string without knowing structure and data type on compile time

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm trying to query a database to get data, convert it to json file and send it to another service. Because those queries can have any column in any table it is impossible to define all structures and data types. I was trying to use sqlx lib but whatever I do MssqlRow won't compile because it cannot infer the type.

Each row should be separate json, so no list of jsons.

Jsons show be created in service, not on db level.

Comment: Is just asking SQL Server to produce the JSON an option? See (e.g.) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43587311/4137916) (some approaches do not require that you know the table structure).

Comment: Not really because I will do some operations like hash and modulo on first column and then convert it to json.

Comment: That's a different question.